# How to split a string without list

Tags: python, split

My file was `Masterdata.xlsx`

When i split the above data my output should be `Masterdata` not `['Masterdata','twbx']`

Code i used is

```
 File_name="Masterdata.xlsx"
 File_name=File_name.split(".",1)
```

Request you to help on this

Comment: you need to put the filename between quotes. `File_name="Masterdata.xlsx"`

Comment: `File_name.split(".",1)[0]`

Comment: @deceze: Or slightly more Pythonically for this specific case, `name, ext = os.path.splitext(File_name)`

Comment: Where does "twbx" come from?

Comment: Maybe `Masterdata` is a dataclass and `xlsx` is an attribute with the value `"Masterdata.twbx"` That would be consistent with the code.

Comment: @Sayse--thats my file extension like xlsx,xls,csv...We have  twbx and twb in tableau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
File_name = 'Masterdata.xlsx'
File_name  = File_name.rsplit( ".", 1 )[ 0 ]
```

Another option from `pathlib` :

```
from pathlib import Path

File_name = Path('Masterdata.xlsx')
File_name = File_name.with_suffix('')
```

and for newer Python (>= 3.9) there is `removesuffix`:

```
File_name = 'Masterdata.xlsx'
File_name = File_name.removesuffix('.xlsx')
```